# Uploadify show alert before file open dialog appears

Tags: jquery, flash-cs5

I am using [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) Flash Version control using jQuery and ASP.NET. All is working fine. My problem is that I need to show an alert when a user click on select file button, before that dialog opens for selecting files to upload. I am using Uploadify JS v1.6.2. I Tried `OnDialogOpen` and onOpen  too. However its not working. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know uploadify but basically it should work like this:

your jQuery:

```
$("#fileInput").click(function() {
  alert("alert!");
});
```

your file input:

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" />
```

Comment: Thanks Jan for your reply. However, in uploadify input control converts into <embed> flash object, so above code wont work in case of uploadify. Do you know about any other method for achieving this.

Comment: the [onDialogOpen](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/ondialogopen/) (statring with a small letter!) function should work. Maybe you can provide us with some code?